# Show that the osculating plane at every point on the curve $r(t) = (t+2, 1-t, t^2/2)$ is the same plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that the osculating plane at every point on the curve $r(t) = (t+2, 1-t, t^2/2)$ is the same plane. What can you conclude about the curve?

What I think is that the curve lies within a single plane, and maybe has something to do with the fact that $x$ and $y$ are linear equations. But I don't know how to proceed from there, please help me.

Comment: What do you know about the osculating plane?  What is its relationship to the velocity and acceleration (or "tangent" and "normal") vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a homework question, I will present the theoretical framework and allow you to work out the details.

Let $r:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth curve. Then the osculating plane at a point, $t$, is defined as $$\text{osc}(t)=r(t)+\langle r'(t),r''(t)\rangle$$
where $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $t$.

When you have finished differentiating, you will be able to make the previous equation explicit. You will need to do some relatively simple linear algebra to simplify the resulting set of vectors (essentially, row-reducing the vectors).

After sufficient simplification, you will be able to remove all instances of $t$, thus showing that the plane is independent of $t$. Incidentally, you will now have the equation of the plane that is osculating at every point of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove your conjecture that the curve is planar without using calculus: Compute the three points
$$a:=r(-2)=\ldots,\quad b:=r(0)=\ldots,\quad c:=r(2)=\ldots$$ on the given curve and the cross product $q:=(b-a)\times(c-a)$. Then prove that the scalar product
$q\cdot\bigl(r(t)-a\bigr)$ is identically zero.